# Skype Web SDK Person Status update Issue + Resolution Issue

Tags: azure, skype, lync, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am using Skype Web SDK to develop an Web Application using Skype For Business and constantly confronting two big issues.

**1. Person's status update issue**

On the main page, it shows the list of 'Persons' from my contact list and 
my code automatically detects the change of status of each person.

If the person is in neither Online nor Available, others cannot click that person, which means cannot establish a call with that person.

I have 6 SfB accounts available (let's say A to F)
For testing, I only used five accounts, A ~ E, and kept the F as offline.

***The ISSUE*** starts here.
Occasionally, A ~ E see F as 'Online' even though F is clearly offline.
Let's say B sees F as 'Online' and tries to call others. 
The moment B clicks 'Call' button, the client freezes and do not respond.
After a minute or two, it establishes the call properly.

The weird thing is that, even though the call doesn't involve F, this 'freezing' happens.

If B tries to call F, it also gives the same issue at the beginning but even after a minute or two, the call doesn't happen (this is obvious because F is not online).

**2. Video call resolution**

If I create a video call from my web application, the resolution is extremely low even though I'm using Full HD webcam for each of my devices.
The resolution is perfectly fine when I'm using SfB application but not for web version.

If anyone can verify what can be a potential reason for these issues and suggest solution for it, it'll be appreciated!

Thanks!